# Data Prepper Pipelines + OpenSearch Trace Analytics

Tags: amazon-web-services, opensearch, open-telemetry, apm

I'm using the latest version of AWS OpenSearch but somehow, when I'm trying to go to the Trace analytics Dashboard it does not show the traces sent by the Data Prepper.

- Manual OpenTelemetry instrumented application
- Data Prepper is running in a Docker (`opensearchproject/data-prepper:latest`)
- OpenSearch is running on the latest version

**Sample Configuration**

`data-prepper-config.yaml`

```yaml
ssl: false
```

`pipelines.yaml`

```yaml
entry-pipeline:
  delay: "100"
  source:
    otel_trace_source:
      ssl: false
  sink:
    - pipeline:
        name: "raw-pipeline"
    - pipeline:
        name: "service-map-pipeline"
raw-pipeline:
  delay: "100"
  source:
    pipeline:
      name: "entry-pipeline"
  processor:
    - otel_trace_raw:
  sink:
    - opensearch:
        hosts: [ "https://opensearch-domain" ]
        username: "admin"
        password: "admin"
        index_type: trace-analytics-raw
service-map-pipeline:
  delay: "100"
  source:
    pipeline:
      name: "entry-pipeline"
  processor:
    - service_map_stateful:
  sink:
    - opensearch:
        hosts: ["https://opensearch-domain"]
        username: "admin"
        password: "admin"
        index_type: trace-analytics-service-map
```

`remote-collector.yaml`

```yaml
...
exporters:
  otlp/data-prepper:
    endpoint: data-prepper-address:21890

service:
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      exporters: [otlp/data-prepper]
```

When I try to go to the Query Workbench and run the query `SELECT * FROM otel-v1-apm-span`, I'm getting the list of received trace spans. But I'm unable to see a chart or something on the Trace Analytics Dashboard (both Traces and Services). It's just an empty dashboard.

I'm also getting a warning:

```json
WARN  org.opensearch.dataprepper.plugins.processor.oteltrace.OTelTraceRawProcessor - Missing trace group for SpanId: xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

The `traceGroupFields` are also empty.

```json
"traceGroupFields": {
  "endTime": null,
  "durationInNanos": null,
  "statusCode": null
}
```

Is there something wrong with my setup? Any help is appreciated.